# How to evaluate whether a string is null?

Tags: java

I have a string, which is read from a database. The string can be just "null".  I need to decide whether it is null or not?  Among the following ones, what is the appropriate way to do it?

```
String a = …;
If  (a == null)

If ( a.length == 0)
```

I also see something like

```
If  a.equals(“ “)
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if (a == null)`

In Java, `==` compares **references**, so you can check to see whether the **reference a** refers to null. `a.length` and `a.equals` would throw [NullPointerException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)s if `a` equaled null, since you can't call methods on null.

When you compare Strings with [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), that:

> is true if and only if the
>   argument is not null and is a String
>   object that represents the same
>   sequence of characters as this object.

So even if we *could* call equals on null (which we can't, as mentioned before), it'd never return true anyway, as according to the documentation.

[String.length](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) would return zero only if `a` equaled `""`, an empty string. As according to the method:

> Returns the length of this string. The
>   length is equal to the number of
>   Unicode code units in the string.

When in doubt, just test it out! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you check for a null `String` value in java:

```
String a = ...;
if (a == null) {
    // ...
}
```

The following throws a `NullPointerException` because a is `null`:

```
String a = null;
if (a.length() == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

The following checks for an empty string, which is different than `null`! (And if `a` is `null`, it will also throw a `NullPointerException`)

```
String a = ...;
if (a.equals("")) {
    // ...
}
```

The following (similar to above), checks for a one character string containing a single space character. (And if `a` is `null`, it will also throw a `NullPointerException`)

```
String a = ...;
if (a.equals(" ")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like something you could just easily test, but in Java you use

```
if( a == null ) ...
```

to test if a String is `null`.

Your second example should be

```
if( a.length() == 0)
```

which just tests to see if the String is *empty*, not `null`.  The value `""` would have a length of 0.  That example would throw an exception if `a` really is `null`, because you can't call a method on a `null` reference in Java.

Your last example is testing to see if the String is a space character.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how your database library interprets NULL values in the database.

Some may pass them through as a `null` string, some may pass them through as the empty string, some may throw an exception - it all depends on how you have it configured and what software you are using.

Without knowing what DB accessor you are using it is impossible to answer this question for certain.

Answer (score 1):

I use ...

```
if(string == null || string.trim.length() == 0) {
 // string is null or empty
}
```

That being said there is also the NULL value from the database and that you should check when going through the ResultSet. Such as ...

```
String nameVal = rs.getString ("name");
   if (rs.wasNull ())
       nameVal = "(no name available)";
```

SQL is tristate in the case of Nullable columns. A column can have a value, A column can be NULL or a column can contain an empty String. NULL has a definite meaning that you need to keep in mind when programming database code.

Answer (score 0):

if( a != null && a.length == 0 )
  // Then it's empty

Answer (score 0):

I would use `if (a == null)` for semantic reasons. Right there you are being very clear you are checking for a null string.

Answer (score 0):

If the string can be the actual value "null" then use

```
if(a.equals("null"))
```

If the object can be set to NULL then use

```
if(a == null)
```

The best thing is to combine them

```
if(a == null || a.equals("null"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have :

```
String test = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
```

You should :

```
if ( test.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
      dosomething...
}else {
       dosomething... 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
try{
    methodWhichUsesTheString(a);
}catch (Exception NullPointerException){
    //string a seems to be null
    a = "Re-assign some desired value that would make things work" ;
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to test the string *before* calling the method.

Comment: This is nothing more than a test to see whether calling the method throws a NPE. That is completely orthogonal to the issue of whether the argument is null. (E.g. if the method is a plain old setter, there will be no NPE even if the arg is null; alternatively, the method can throw a NPE even if the arg is not null.)